# Django form field label- how to change its value 'if' it belongs to a certain field

Tags: python, django, forms, formatting, label

I have a Django form, and the fields/ field labels for the form are all displayed using a `for` loop:

```
{% load utilities %}

{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {% if field|is_checkbox %}
        <tr><td colspan="1">{{field}}</td><td colspan="6"><label>{{field.label}}</label></td></tr>
    {% else %}
        <tr><td colspan="7"><label>{{field.label}}</label></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="7">{{field}}
        </td></tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to add some text to the labels for certain fields displayed by this `for` loop (if the field is a 'date' field, I want to instruct the user to enter values in the format 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm').

I know that if the field is a 'date' field, its name will contain the word 'date', so how can I nest an `if` inside the `if` statement here, to say:

```
if field.name contains "date":
    field.name = field.name + "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"
```

I understand the logic of how to do this, I'm just not sure about the Python syntax... would it be something like:

```
{% if "string" in {{field.name}} %}
    {{field.name}} = {{field.name}} + " (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm)"
```

I gave this a go, but my browser displayed a syntax error that said:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /projects/5915/info/
>
> Could not parse the remainder: '{{field.label}}' from '{{field.label}}'

**Edit**

My form definition currently looks like this:

```
class CdiInitialDetailsForm(ValidatedForm):
    """ Top left box on CDI Proposal tab. Updated budget not part of the form, in HTML """
    vat_status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(0, 0),(5,5),(20,20)], required=False,)
    meeting_date = mDateTimeField(required=False, label="Site visit date (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm)", widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')) 
    discussed_budget_updated = forms.IntegerField(required=False, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs=({'class':'currency'})), label='Updated budget exc VAT')
    discussed_budget_updated_inc = forms.IntegerField(required=False, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs=({'readonly':'readonly', 'class':'currency'})), label="Inc vat")
    site_visitor_1 = forms.CharField()
    site_visitor_2 = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = InitialDetails
        fields = ['chance','vat_status','discussed_budget_updated','discussed_budget_updated_inc','meeting_date','site_visitor_1','site_visitor_2']
        labels = {
            "meeting_date": "Meeting date (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm): "
        }


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', {})
        project = instance.project

        #Get site visit date, who visited site, vat status
        try:
            meeting = project.meetings.get(purpose=1)
            meeting_date = meeting.date
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            meeting_date = None

        visited_site = project.assigned.select_related('employee').filter(role=Role.VS)
        try: site_visitor_1 = visited_site[0].employee.id
        except IndexError: site_visitor_1 = None
        try: site_visitor_2 = visited_site[1].employee.id
        except IndexError: site_visitor_2 = None
        try: vat_status = project.vat_status
        except: vat_status = 0

        try: discussed_budget_updated = int(round(instance.discussed_budget_updated))
        except: discussed_budget_updated = None
        try: discussed_budget_updated_inc = int(round(instance.discussed_budget_updated_inc_vat))
        except: discussed_budget_updated_inc = None

        initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
        initial={
                'meeting_date': meeting_date,
                'vat_status': vat_status,
                'site_visitor_1': site_visitor_1,
                'site_visitor_2': site_visitor_2,
                'discussed_budget_updated': discussed_budget_updated,
                'discussed_budget_updated_inc': discussed_budget_updated_inc,
                }
        kwargs['initial'] = initial
    
        super(CdiInitialDetailsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['site_visitor_1'] = AutoFlexiSelect(model='e', choices=get_choices('EMPLOYEE_CHOICES'), current_id=site_visitor_1, label="Who visited site")
        self.fields['site_visitor_2'] = AutoFlexiSelect(model='e', choices=get_choices('EMPLOYEE_CHOICES'), current_id=site_visitor_2, label="&")
        chance = self.instance.chance
        if chance:
            in_choices = [choice for choice in InitialDetails.CHANCE_CHOICES if chance in choice]
            if not in_choices:
                self.fields['chance'].choices = [(chance, chance)] + self.fields['chance'].choices
                self.fields['chance'].initial = chance
```

Would I need to add the `labels` to the `__init__` method?

Comment: Are you trying to update the value of `field` within the template? OR, just want to display the value of `{{field.name}} + " (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm)"`?

Comment: I'm just trying to change the label of the field to `{{field.name}} (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm)`, the actual field itself takes input in the format 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm', so I want to add that format instruction to the field label, so that the user knows what format to type into the field.

Comment: There is validation on the field, so that it won't accept any input that's not in this format, but at the moment, there's nothing to indicate to the user that this is the format that they should type into the field.

Comment: Not sure, but i do not think you can do that within template. I think you should create a template tag to transform the content to the value you desire

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within in your view, before passing the form, you could access the form and check change specific field types. You can alter each field via `form.fields[<fieldname>]` and the attributes linked to it.

A better way would be to do it directly in your `forms.py` or wherever you have defined your form.

```
class ExampleForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = ("field1", "field2")
        labels = {
            "field1": "I have a custom label",
        }
```

If you really want to do it within the template, use a Templatetag.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/

With {{ forms.field.widget| }} you could get the type within your custom filter and then return either `True` or `False`

**Edit**

As it turns out that the label should be a dynamic parameter coming from the database, you can try something like this:

in views.py

`form = ExampleForm(some_label='abc')`

in forms.py

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.some_label = kwargs.pop('some_label')
        self.fields['some_field'].label = self.some_label
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer- I tried changing it in the form as you suggested- added the lines for the `labels`, but this doesn't appear to have changed what's actually displayed...

Comment: Have you made sure that `labels` is under `class Meta:` and that the field name is spelt correctly? I have just tried it myself and it works. Maybe add your Form to your post so it is easier to see what you could have done wrong.

Comment: Yes, `labels` is under `class Meta:`, and the field name is spelt correctly- I'll update my OP to show the form now.

Comment: Ok. `ValidatedForm` is your own Class? I guess I misunderstood your question as you using a `ModelForm` and wanting to overwrite the default labels. Do you use this Form in different situations and need to change the label names dynamically? Otherwise you could just change the label string right when creating `meeting_date`. I guess `labels = {}` doesn't work here because you defined the label right above it.

Comment: The 'label' value actually being used on the form will be coming from a database- it will be one of the column headings, as every object of this type in the database has one of these values.

Comment: The form is used for one situation- but with many instances of that situation (i.e. several different 'projects')

Comment: Would I need to add the `label` field to the `__init__` method, to ensure that its values are displayed on the form?

Comment: Updated my answer. I can't test it right now but I hope it works or at least leads you to the answer quickly :S